# $u(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{G} \Bigl[\nabla_y \frac{1}{\lvert x-y\rvert} \Bigr] \times \omega(y) dy+A(x)$ for $\omega=\nabla \times u$ and harmonic $A$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $U$ be an open region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $G \subset U$ be another open set whose closure is compact in $U$.

Then, for any smooth divergence-free $u : U \to \mathbb{R}^3$, I ran into the statement that
\begin{equation}
u(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{G} \Bigl[\nabla_y \frac{1}{\lvert x-y\rvert} \Bigr] \times \omega(y) dy+A(x) \text{ for } x \in G
\end{equation}
where $\omega=\nabla \times u$ and $A : G \to \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies $\Delta A=0$ componentwise.

There is no detailed proof and just a brief mention of Hodge's Theorem. But, I cannot see how to make use of the theorem. Also, I have difficulty with proving the formula directly with vector calculus..

Could anyone please help me?

Edit : I forgot the divergence-free condition for $u$, so I add it to the main body.

Comment: You might look for DeTurck and Gluck's papers on the Biot-Savart operator in three dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you integrate your expression by parts, your integrand becomes $-\frac{\nabla_y\times\omega(y)}{|x-y|}$, and the numerator is just the vector Laplacian of $u$ since

$$\nabla\times\nabla\times u = \nabla(\nabla\cdot u) - \Delta u = -\Delta u$$

due to the divergence free condition on $u$. So your statement is asserting that

$$u = K*\Delta u + A + \text{boundary term}$$

Where $K(x)=1/(4\pi |x|)$ is the Green’s function for the Laplacian. This is also known as Green’s representation formula, which you can find a proof of in Gilbarg and Trudinger’s Elliptic PDEs book, page 17-18. Clearly $A$ plus the boundary term (arising from integrating by parts) is harmonic, you might need to use the explicit representation given in Gilbarg-Trudinger to show that $A$ is. Morally speaking, convolution with $K$ inverts the Laplacian (at least on $\mathbb{R}^n$) and the presence of $A$ is to compensate for the fact there’s a boundary.

Comment: Thank you. If I set $U=G$ to be $3$ dimensional torus and assume periodic boundary conditions, then I guess the boundary term just vanishes? In that case, I think $A$ is also just a constant vector.

Comment: Yes, the boundary terms should vanish. You’d probably need to be working with the flat torus (say, unit cube with sides identified) otherwise the Laplacian would change.

Comment: Oh yes, I of course mean just the flat torus. Thanknl you!

Comment: I resolved the issue myself so I just deleted the question. I am sorry for confusion.